# bad URI(is not URI?) while testing | Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I`ve got these strange issues I dont know how to fix it. Please help me if you can.

Here is a testing result:

```
1) Admin can edit a hotel
     Failure/Error: visit edit_admin_hotel_path(hotel)
     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): 
     # ./spec/requests/admin_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Admin can edit a user
     Failure/Error: visit edit_admin_user_path(admin)
     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): 
     # ./spec/requests/admin_spec.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

`rake routes` shows me nice edit routes for users and hotels:

```
edit_admin_hotel  GET  /admin/hotels/:id/edit(.:format)   admin/hotels#edit
edit_admin_user   GET  /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/users#edit
```

And everything works just fine if I start server and check it manually. So I have no idea where these issues comes from. Thanks for any help!
And my admin_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Admin"  do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:hotel) { FactoryGirl.create(:hotel) }


    before(:each) do
        sign_up_as_admin admin
        visit admin_hotels_path
    end

    subject { page }

    it { expect(page).to have_content("Manage Hotels") }
    it { expect(page).to have_content("Manage Users") }
    it { expect(page).to have_link("Sign out") }
    it { expect(page).to have_content("List of hotels") }
    it { expect(page).to have_content("Hello, Admin") }

    it "can add a hotel" do
        click_link "Add Hotel"
        expect(current_path).to eq(new_admin_hotel_path)
        fill_in 'name', with: "TestHotel"
        fill_in 'price', with: "666"
        fill_in 'star_rating', with: "5"
        expect { click_button "Submit" }.to change(Hotel,:count).by(1)
        expect(current_path).to eq(admin_hotel_path(1))
    end

    it "can edit a hotel" do
        visit edit_admin_hotel_path(hotel)
    end

    it "can delete a hotel" do
        visit admin_hotel_path(hotel)
        expect { click_link "Delete hotel" }.to change(Hotel,:count).by(-1)
        #expect { click_link "Delete hotel" }.to redirect_to(admin_hotels_path)
    end

    it "can create a new user" do
        click_link "Add User"
        expect(current_path).to eq(new_admin_user_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("Create New User")
        fill_in "Name",    :with => "user"
        fill_in "Email",    :with => "user@auser.com"
        fill_in "Password", :with => "user.password"
        fill_in "password_confirmation", :with => "user.password"
        expect { click_button "Create User" }.to change(User,:count).by(1)
        expect(current_path).to eq(admin_users_path)
    end

    it "can edit a user" do
        visit edit_admin_user_path(admin)
    end
end
```

Edit/update actions in users_controller.rb:

```
# GET admin/users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render "edit", status: 302
  end

  # PATCH/PUT admin/users/1
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.try(:update_attributes, user_params)
      render "edit", notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end
```

And user/edit.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
    <% end %>
      <%= button_to 'Delete User', [:admin, @user], :data => {     confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 1:**
I found out that these `bad URI(is not URI?)` errors also in hotel_controller and comment_controller while testing edit action. These errors in all of my controllers in edit actions and I dont know what cousing them :(

Comment: What does `puts edit_admin_hotel_path(hotel).inspect` show?

Comment: @Andy Waite `"/admin/hotels/1/edit"`

Comment: If you print in the spec `edit_admin_hotel_path(hotel)` before passing it to the `visit` helper, what is the value?

Comment: If you specify backtrace when you run rspec (-b), does it point to some other line than the spec? Also, when you printed out the path, did you print it from your spec? Finally, you might try printing `edit_admin_hotel_url(hotel).inspect`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your edit action is wrong:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render "edit", status: 302
end
```

A 302 status means that the response is a redirect and that the `Location` header in the response contains the URI (relative or absolute) to redirect to. Capybara will be looking for this header and probably winds up trying to do `URI.parse(nil)`.

It's not clear to me why you are setting the status here at all

Answer (score 0):

In your spec_helper have you included the url_helpers?

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did now but tests still falling.